# How to fix: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a simple search bar but the first time you type something in it you get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
```

When I close the pop up and type the search bar it works.

```js
function Search(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === '') {
        setFilteredData(backendData);
    } else {
        setFilteredData(filteredData.filter(el => el.childName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())));
    }
}
```

Comment: the  ?.  will work but this is not good. you are not fix it just cover the bug. give us more information and more code to help. 
calling Search function etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter data or query is undefined.

```js
function Search(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === '') {
        setFilteredData(backendData);
    } else {
        setFilteredData(filteredData => filteredData?.filter(el => el.childName.toLowerCase().includes(query?.toLowerCase())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
setFilteredData(filteredData.filter((el) => {
    console.log('el', el);
    if (el && typeof el?.childName == 'string' && typeof query == 'string') {
        return el?.childName?.toLowerCase()?.includes(query?.toLowerCase())
    } else return false;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the first time the `el.childName` or `query` are undefined.

Could you try this?

```
function Search(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);

    if (event.target.value === '' || !el.childName || !query) {
        setFilteredData(backendData);
    } else {
        setFilteredData(filteredData.filter(el => el.childName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should set `query` and `filteredData` in the same function (that makes `query` state itself pointless). A more common approach is to use a `useEffect` to change the `filteredData` accordingly:

```js
function Search(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (!backendData) return;

    if (query) {
        setFilteredData(backendData.filter(el => el.childName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())));
    } else {
        setFilteredData(backendData);
    }
}, [query, backendData]);
```